# How to sign a transaction locally using python?

Tags: nodeos, keosd, python, signing

I want to sign a transaction to use it with the rpc endpoint `v1/chain/push_transaction`.

Until nodeos v.1.1 its was explained [in the docs](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/v1.1.0/reference#wallet_unlock) on how to use nodeos (probably keosd indirectly) to do wallet operations like signing.
Now it seems like this is gone. starting a local node still logs:

> keosd [...] add api url: /v1/wallet/sign_transaction

But if I try to use this endpoint it gives me a 404 error.
Is there any other way of signing the transaction using python?

Edit:
My request looks like this

```
[{
        "expiration": "2018-10-26T15:30:32.000",
        "ref_block_num": 21149807,
        "ref_block_prefix": 3590041248,
        "context_free_actions": [],
        "actions": [{
            "account": "eosio.token",
            "name": "transfer",
            "authorization": [{
                "actor": "testertimohe",
                "permission": "active"
            }],
            "data": "0000000000ea305500000000487a2b9d102700000000000004454f53000000001163726561746564206279206e6f70726f6d"
        }],
        "signatures": []
    },
    ["EOS6gXwNz2SKUNAZcyjzVvg6KdNgA1bSuVzCr8c5yWkGij52JKx8V"], ""
]
r = requests.post(
    f'http://localhost:8888/v1/wallet/sign_transaction', json=data)
response = json.loads(r.text)
```

I am getting the ref_block_num and ref_block_predix from /get_block and /get_info and the data from /abi_json_to_bin

What I see in the nodeos logs:

> nodeosd_1  | debug 2018-10-25T08:29:34.909 thread-0 
>   http_plugin.cpp:296           handle_http_request  ] 404 - not found:
>   /v1/wallet/sign_transaction

Generally my understanding is that because you don't send the private key but the public key it probably looks in your keos wallet if this public key exists and then takes the private key from there to sign, is that right?

Comment: The documentation is now in keosd https://developers.eos.io/keosd/v1.3.0/reference#sign_transaction

Comment: Yes, I also found that out, but I am having some problems with it. please have a look at my comment for the answer below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are missing here is the chain ID of the network.

Mainnet: `aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906`

Jungle Testnet: `e70aaab8997e1dfce58fbfac80cbbb8fecec7b99cf982a9444273cbc64c41473`

It has to be added in the " " field just after the key.

**Your request for Jungle Testnet should be:**

```
[{
        "expiration": "2018-10-26T15:30:32.000",
        "ref_block_num": 21149807,
        "ref_block_prefix": 3590041248,
        "context_free_actions": [],
        "actions": [{
            "account": "eosio.token",
            "name": "transfer",
            "authorization": [{
                "actor": "testertimohe",
                "permission": "active"
            }],
            "data": "0000000000ea305500000000487a2b9d102700000000000004454f53000000001163726561746564206279206e6f70726f6d"
        }],
        "signatures": []
    },
    ["EOS6gXwNz2SKUNAZcyjzVvg6KdNgA1bSuVzCr8c5yWkGij52JKx8V"], "e70aaab8997e1dfce58fbfac80cbbb8fecec7b99cf982a9444273cbc64c41473"
]
r = requests.post(
    f'http://localhost:8888/v1/wallet/sign_transaction', json=data)
response = json.loads(r.text)
```

Also, make sure that `keosd` is running at the port 8888. And the private key is imported into the wallet and wallet is unlocked.

Good luck..!

Answer (score 3):

The api '/v1/wallet' is from the server keosd, not the nodeosd. You may change the port that keosd served.

Comment: I am not able to connect to keos directly: 
`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:  
 HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8900): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/wallet/create (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x10eed2da0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))`

Also in the docks they use port 8888 which would be nodeos not keosd directly:
https://developers.eos.io/keosd/v1.3.0/reference#create     

can you give me an example of a call which works for you?

Comment: I can somewhat call keos on port 9876 but I am getting this response `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))` and on nodeos it says "incoming message length unexpected"